# JENA : Create a single Statement based on a String object

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, jena

I have to parse N-TRIPLE content and apply a modification on every literal of a given type.

For example, I have to modify every WKTLiteral to make them using a referential. Triples such as :

```
"POINT (0.0 0.0)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>
```

Must become :

```
"<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326> POINT (0.0 0.0)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>
```

I got each triple line by line into String object and would like to create Jena Statement from this String. My aim is to use the Jena parsers to avoid some dirty String manipulation such as split that are error prone.

For now the only way I find to do this is :

```java
String line = "%a triple is here%";
//Create an empty model
final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
//Parse and store the RDF triple in the model
RDFDataMgr.read(model, new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), Lang.NTRIPLES);
//Get all the statements - only 1 if any
final StmtIterator listStatements = model.listStatements();
//Got my statement
final Statement statement = listStatements.next();
```

I also tried to use an RDFReader but don't know to use then a RDFOutputStream...
To only get a Statement object automatically created from a String I have to create a Model,use a Reader and an Iterator. It seems to be overkill in my opinion (I cutted off most of the test such as testing that there is effectively a next statement...) .

Do you know a kicker/simpler way to achieve this ?

Arthur.

Comment: Can you give some fuller examples of what the input is and what the output is supposed to be?  Am I correct in understanding that you want to change the lexical form of each literal or a given datatype?

Comment: The content is very large, we are talking about RDF file generated by linked geo data - conversion of Open Street Map data to RDF. And the only use case I have is the one I presented, but in order to make the question reusable I tried to make it a little more generic. In fact I need to modify every single WKT to make them correct for Strabon endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find using [streams](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/system/StreamRDF.html) more efficient. [`StreamRDF`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/system/StreamRDF.html) instances are sent [triples](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/graph/Triple.html?is-external=true) as they are encountered. You can then rewrite as appropriate.

Streams use the SPI level of jena -- nodes, triples and quads rather than statements, resources, etc -- which lack some niceities but for tasks like this they are ideal.

Given what you've written I suspect writing out fixed N-Triples is what you want? Here's an example that will do that. All it does is 1) create a stream to output triples, 2) create a stream that waits for triples, corrects the object (if needed), and writes the results and 3) starts the whole parse going:

```
final String wkt = "http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral";

// Stream result to stdout
final StreamRDF outputHandler = StreamRDFLib.writer(System.out);

StreamRDF inputHandler = new StreamRDFBase() {
    @Override
    public void triple(Triple triple) { // Got a triple
        Node object = triple.getObject();

        Node transformed;
        // if object is literal and has wkt type
        if (object.isLiteral() &&
                wkt.equals(object.getLiteralDatatypeURI())) {
            // Make a new node, suitably modified
            transformed = NodeFactory.createLiteral(
                    "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326> " 
                            + object.getLiteralLexicalForm(), 
                    object.getLiteralDatatype());
        } else { // Do nothing
            transformed = object;
        }

        // Write out with corrected object
        outputHandler.triple(
                Triple.create( triple.getSubject(), triple.getPredicate(),
                        transformed
                        ));
    }
};

// Parse 
RDFDataMgr.parse(inputHandler, RDFDataMgr.open("file"));
```

Comment: +1 I provided a SPARQL-based answer, in case the data is already in a triple store, but I think this stream-based approach is probably best.

Comment: I'll try to flesh this out. It's a bit brief :-)

Comment: I look forward to seeing the expanded version.  While code samples are always nice, sometimes it's enough to point out the right classes and let users read the Javadocs.  Sometimes it's just hard to find the right API in the first place.

Comment: Arthur Vaïsse: your edit was rejected apparently, but you're quite right about the NPE. wkt.equals(...) should fix it.

Comment: Hum, yeah this way also fix it. The code is valid, now, this is the only important thing, in case someone else reuse it. Thanks for your time, user205512!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you'll find a better way than what you've got, really, except that you should probably read in chunks of the file rather than each individual line.  If you read in chunks of the file, then you can transform the whole chunk using a simple construct SPARQL query.  That will provide a new model, and you can append the N-TRIPLE serialization of that model to your output file (or insert it into a new graph, etc.).  Suppose you've got this data:

```
<urn:ex:a> <urn:ex:p> <urn:ex:b>.
<urn:ex:c> <urn:ex:q> "POINT (0.0 0.0)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>.
```

Then a query like this will produce the following updated model:

```sql
construct { ?s ?p ?oo }
where {

  #-- constant values pulled out for readability; this
  #-- is optional, of course.
  values (?dt ?prefix) {
    (<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>
    "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326> ") 
  }

  #-- grab each triple, and bind ?oo to ?o if it doesn't 
  #-- need to be updated, or to a new literal, if it does.
  ?s ?p ?o .
  bind( if( isLiteral(?o) && datatype(?o) = ?dt,
            strdt( concat(?prefix,str(?o)), ?dt ),
            ?o )
        as ?oo )
}
```

```
<urn:ex:a> <urn:ex:p> <urn:ex:b> .
<urn:ex:c> <urn:ex:q> "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326> POINT (0.0 0.0)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral> .
```

If you were to load the whole dataset into a TDB instance, you could transform the whole dataset relatively easily with some variant of this, and then just dump the final data into a new file.

Comment: I think this answer will be helpful if you already have the data in a big triple store, but if it's just in some files, then [user205512's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25366818/1281433) is probably a much better solution.

Comment: You could adjust this to be an SPARQL update, of course.

Comment: This is an interesting solution but not suitable for my case. I'll use RDFStream. But, thanks for your time Joshua!